# TypeError: TimeGrouper.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'freq'

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

What am I doing wrong?

This is all the code needed to reproduce.

```py
import pandas as pd
g = pd.Grouper('datetime', freq='D')
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 g = pd.Grouper('datetime', freq='D')

TypeError: TimeGrouper.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'freq'
```

Pandas version 1.5.1, Python version 3.10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This seems to be a bug

It looks like the weirdness is because [`Grouper.__new__()` instantiates a `TimeGrouper` if you pass `freq` as a kwarg](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.1/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py#L268-L274), but not if you pass `freq` as a positional argument. I don't know why it does that, and it's [not documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5.1/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), so it seems like a bug.

The reason for the error is that [`TimeGrouper.__init__()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.1/pandas/core/resample.py#L1586-L1603)'s first parameter is `freq`, not `key`. (In fact it doesn't even have a `key` parameter; it specifies `**kwargs`, [which are then sent to `Grouper.__init__()` at the end](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.1/pandas/core/resample.py#L1688).)

#### Workaround

Pass `key` as a kwarg too:

```
g = pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')
```

#### All-positional syntax is also broken

In [cottontail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74634898/4518341), they suggested using positional arguments, with `None` for *level*, but this doesn't work fully. For example, you can't specify an *origin*:

```
pd.Grouper('datetime', None, 'D', origin='epoch')
```

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'origin'
```

(I'm using Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.4.4, so the error might look a bit different, but the same error should occur on your version.)

Even worse, the resulting `Grouper` doesn't work, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.to_datetime([
        '2022-11-29T15', '2022-11-30T15', '2022-11-30T16']),
    'v': [1, 2, 3]})
```

```
>>> g = pd.Grouper('datetime', None, 'D')
>>> df.groupby(g).sum()
                     v
datetime              
2022-11-29 15:00:00  1
2022-11-30 15:00:00  2
2022-11-30 16:00:00  3
```

Compared to:

```
>>> g1 = pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')
>>> df.groupby(g1).sum()
            v
datetime     
2022-11-29  1
2022-11-30  5
```

Comment: Nice catch on `TimeGrouper` not having `key` at all. I removed the misinformation on my post. It certainly is an *interesting* design which will probably get corrected in future pandas versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the keyword argument `key`:

```py
g = pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')
print(type(g))
# pandas.core.resample.TimeGrouper
```

As explained in [wjandrea's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74635314/19123103), `TimeGrouper` is instantiated only if `freq` kwarg is passed. For example, the following instantiates a `Grouper`:

```py
g1 = pd.Grouper('datetime', None, pd.offsets.Day())
print(type(g1))
# pandas.core.groupby.grouper.Grouper
```

even though, `g1.freq` is an instance of `pd._libs.tslibs.offsets.Day`. So it looks like passing the arguments via keywords is the only way.

Comment: Using positional arguments doesn't work fully. [I posted my own answer with details](/a/74635314/4518341).