Why is there an error 'TypeError: Grouper.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base''?
Versions needed to be known :

Jupyter Notebook : 6.5.4

Python : 3.11.3

Pandas : 2.2.2

xarray : 2022.11.0


I am doing an assignment by using a precipitation dataset from http://research.jisao.washington.edu/data_sets/widmann/ to perform sensor selection (where should you place sensor to best predict rain).
First, I opened the file and read it, using the code below :
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

nc_file_path = './pnwrain.50km.daily.4994.nc' 
dataset = xr.open_dataset(nc_file_path,decode_times=False)
dataset 

Output :
image1 
Then, I convert the time variable into datetime, using the code below :
ref_date = pd.to_datetime('1949-01-01')
# Convert 'time' variable to datetimes
dataset['time'] = ref_date + pd.to_timedelta(dataset['time'], unit='D') 

After that, I calculate the monthly totals in months, using the code below :
monthly_totals = dataset['data'].resample(time='ME').sum()

Output :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 monthly_totals = dataset['data'].resample(time='ME').sum()
      3 print("Monthly totals: ", monthly_totals)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataarray.py:6636, in DataArray.resample(self, indexer, skipna, closed, label, base, keep_attrs, loffset, restore_coord_dims, **indexer_kwargs)
   6540 """Returns a Resample object for performing resampling operations.
   6541 
   6542 Handles both downsampling and upsampling. The resampled
   (...)
   6632 .. [1] http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases
   6633 """
   6634 from .resample import DataArrayResample
-> 6636 return self._resample(
   6637     resample_cls=DataArrayResample,
   6638     indexer=indexer,
   6639     skipna=skipna,
   6640     closed=closed,
   6641     label=label,
   6642     base=base,
   6643     keep_attrs=keep_attrs,
   6644     loffset=loffset,
   6645     restore_coord_dims=restore_coord_dims,
   6646     **indexer_kwargs,
   6647 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py:965, in DataWithCoords._resample(self, resample_cls, indexer, skipna, closed, label, base, keep_attrs, loffset, restore_coord_dims, **indexer_kwargs)
    963         grouper = CFTimeGrouper(freq, closed, label, base, loffset)
    964     else:
--> 965         grouper = pd.Grouper(
    966             freq=freq, closed=closed, label=label, base=base, loffset=loffset
    967         )
    968 group = DataArray(
    969     dim_coord, coords=dim_coord.coords, dims=dim_coord.dims, name=RESAMPLE_DIM
    970 )
    971 return resample_cls(
    972     self,
    973     group=group,
   (...)
    977     restore_coord_dims=restore_coord_dims,
    978 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py:2208, in TimeGrouper.__init__(self, obj, freq, key, closed, label, how, axis, fill_method, limit, kind, convention, origin, offset, group_keys, **kwargs)
   2205 # always sort time groupers
   2206 kwargs["sort"] = True
-> 2208 super().__init__(freq=freq, key=key, axis=axis, **kwargs)

TypeError: Grouper.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base'

Do anyone know why this error is encountered?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Telling the whole story in a reproducible way, for whoever would expand the time to draw the data from the source, is a commendable effort. I wonder however, if it wouldn't be preferable to post as text a sample of the data as it is just before the error-raising line, and skip everything before. That would probably help getting answers.

Anyways, argument 'base' present but not recognized might point to mismatching module versions, maybe of .resample vs xarray. Consider updating?

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74634784/12846804 several hits like this, pointing to actual bug. Search Stackoverflow.

I would try to update Xarray. Pandas 2.2.2 is brand new and Xarray 2022.11.0 is ~2 yrs old. I suspect there is a mismatch there.
